# How to fetch selected data from hibernate criteria api?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I want to fetch data from database for selected queries by using criteria api.

**For example:**

```
select firstname,empid from emp where empid=10 && 
    empname='bhanu' || salary=25000;
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a bit of setup when using the Criteria API as opposed to plain HQL.

The [Criteria API](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/querycriteria.html) documentation is very good and I would recommend you check it out and post back if you have a specific issue.

If this is more a design question, I would ask what are your reasons for choosing Criteria over HQL.

Is there a specific requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Criteria](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch17.html) Query like this:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Emp.class)
    .setProjection( Projections.projectionList()
        .add( Projections.property("firstName") )
        .add( Projections.property("empId") ) );

Criterion criterion= Restrictions.and(Restrictions.eq("empId", 10),
                                      Restrictions.eq("empName", "bhanu"));

criteria.add(Restrictions.or(criterion, Restrictions.eq("salary", 25000)));

List result=criteria.list();
```